# Вывод данных из БД в таблицу html с помощью php

Tags: php, mysql, поиск, динамические-массивы

Уважаемые посетители. Есть вопрос.
Суть ситуации - необходимо вывести данные из базы в таблицу на странице.
Если запись в БД есть, выводить содержимое в ячейку, если нет - отрисовывать пустую клетку в таблице.

Сейчас данные отрисовываются только те, которые возвращает запрос, т.е. данные по которым есть в БД, остальное - игнорируется. Пробовал несколько вариантов вывода.

Есть еще особенность - количество дней, которое показывает соответствует данным из БД, и если смотреть исходный код страницы, то данные о конкретном дне добавились в  с нужным id, но опять же пустых клеток нет.

***Понял в чем проблема:*** массив arr - многомерный, ассоциативный. Не той функцией перебираю его и ищу значение $id в нем. Теперь другая сложность, как найти динамично изменяющийся $id в многомерном ассоциативном массиве. Нашел несколько статей на эту тему, но увы...

Прилагаю скрин.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$id = strtoupper($info[$i]['id'])."-".$gluing_date; // делаю уникальный id для каждого элемента <td>, чтобы записывать данные в нужную ячейку

$sql = "SELECT id, work_date, cause 
          FROM month_detail
         WHERE id = '".strtoupper($info[$i]['id'])."'
           AND work_date = '".$gluing_date."'
        ";  

$query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql); //Выполнение запроса в БД;

// цикл отрисовки ячеек таблицы         
$t=0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $arr[$t]['cause'] = $row['cause'];
    $arr[$t]['concat'] = $row['id']."-".$row['work_date'];

    if (in_array($id,$arr)){ //проверка $id клетки <td> в получаемом массиве, чтобы записать конкретную запись именно в этот id
        echo "<td class='day'; id='".$id."'> ".$arr[$t]['cause']." </td>";  // если $id есть в массиве $arr, то отрисовать <td> с содержимым из БД
    } else {
        echo "<td class='day'; id='".$id."'> &nbsp; </td>"; // если нет - рисовать пустую клетку
    }
    $t++;
}
```

Comment: таблица выводитси? не выводится? что именно работает некоректно?

Comment: Сейчас получается так, что выводит только те, записи, которые есть в БД, остальные клетки, просто-напросто не отрисовываются

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбор, присвоение и логика составлено логически правильно. 
Некорректно подобрана функция, которая осуществляет поиск значения в массиве.

В условии

```
if (in_array($id,$arr)){ //проверка $id клетки <td> в получаемом массиве, чтобы записать конкретную запись именно в этот id
        echo "<td class='day'; id='".$id."'> ".$arr[$t]['cause']." </td>";  // если $id есть в массиве $arr, то отрисовать <td> с содержимым из БД
    } else {
        echo "<td class='day'; id='".$id."'> &nbsp; </td>"; // если нет - рисовать пустую клетку
    }
```

Использовать функцию in_array - недопустимо, так как поиск осуществляется в многомерном ассоциативном массиве. По-этому описанное условие не выполняется.

Answer (score 0):

Вы смотрели исходник страницы, которая выводится?
Если там есть

```
<td></td>
```

то пустые ячейки выводятся, просто их не видно в браузере.

Попробуйте подставить вместо неразрывного пробела какую-нибудь букву и посмотреть, выводится ли она.

Comment: Смотрел исходник, не отрисовывает. Добавление символов вместо &nbsp; - не помогает

Comment: логически рассуждая, в этом случае не выполняется условие else.
Прогоните соответствующие переменные на вывод через var_dump(), где-то и выявится пустая переменная или неработающее условие.

Comment: понял в чем беда, у меня arr - это многомерный ассоциативный массив, а in_array не отрабатывает так как надо. Т.е. мне необходимо динамичную переменную $id искать в многомерном ассоциативном массиве

Comment: var_dump() всегда открывает много неожиданного :)

Answer (score 0):

Задайте ячейкам ширину и высоту с помощью css, можно задать радиус. И будет работать
`<td style="border: 1px solid red; width: 50px; height: 50px;">&nbsp;</td>`
Железно рисует ячейку

Comment: не работает, данные не выводит

Comment: Вы просили, чтобы рисовалась пустая ячейка. Это для нее

Comment: Константин, я прекрасно понял то, что Вы написали, однако если Вы обратите внимание, то в коде, который я приводил есть подобная строка, просто у этого класса отсутствует описания стиля в коде php. Проблема была в другом.